# How to disable the logging of ACRA

Tags: java, android, logging, android-logcat, acra

I'm using ACRA for crash reporting in my app. (In brief, ACRA is a tool for sending crash reports to the developer.)

Even in release builds, I can see its logs in the device's logcat (for example when it sends a crash report, it sends many log lines with "ACRA" tag).

Is there a way to disable its logging?

**Based on the comments below, let me emphasize again:** I'm asking to disable the logging of ACRA itself. The question has nothing to do with ACRA's crashing or with the system logcat during app crashes.

I think the best is to provide an example about what I mean:

```
04-13 02:33:50.980: D/ACRA(4560): Using custom Report Fields
04-13 02:33:51.170: I/ACRA(4560): READ_LOGS not allowed. ACRA will not include LogCat and DropBox data.
04-13 02:33:51.170: D/ACRA(4560): Writing crash report file 1667311131000.stacktrace.
04-13 02:33:51.200: D/ACRA(4560): About to start ReportSenderWorker from #handleException
04-13 02:33:51.200: D/ACRA(4560): Waiting for Toast + worker...
```

Comment: Downvoter, care to offer me some guidance? What's wrong with my developer question? I checked all ACRA documentation but could not find anything. I believe it's a legitimate need from a developer to prevent release builds from exposing their crash reporting specifics to users. Even Google recommends that logcat logging of your own app should be disabled in released apps.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: you misunderstand me. The question has nothing to do with crash reports sent by ACRA. Also, it is *not* about the system log when ACRA crashes (it doesn't crash, it works fine). Again: the question is to disable ACRA's own verbose logging in logcat.

Comment: For that, if you can't figure it out from the documentation then I suggest you look through the ACRA source and see where the those messages are coming from and if there is any method to gate them there already, or if you will need to add one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable ACRA's logging, you might want to use this implementation of the `ACRALog` interface:

```
public class NoAcraLog implements ACRALog {

    @Override
    public int v(String tag, String msg) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int v(String tag, String msg, Throwable tr) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int d(String tag, String msg) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int d(String tag, String msg, Throwable tr) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int i(String tag, String msg) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int i(String tag, String msg, Throwable tr) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int w(String tag, String msg) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int w(String tag, String msg, Throwable tr) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int w(String tag, Throwable tr) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int e(String tag, String msg) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int e(String tag, String msg, Throwable tr) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String getStackTraceString(Throwable tr) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Provide an instance of this class to `ACRA`:

```
ACRA.setLog(new NoAcraLog());
```

This should disable all logging of ACRA since the abovementioned implementation would do nothing. (FYI: normally ACRA uses `AndroidLogDelegate` which redirects log messages to the `Log` class.)

Answer (score 0):

This section on "Enable/disable system logs" may be helpful - https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#enabledisable-system-logs

Comment: Doesn't that section deal with *including* system logs in ACRA *reports*? What I need is disabling the logging of ACRA itself. This has nothing to do with its reports themselves.